# How to decrement by the amount of deleted documents in Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore onWrite triggers?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am stuggeling to decrement a counter in a parent collection of three subcollections after a whole collection is deleted. The structure is built as follows:

courses -> {CourseID} -> Sections -> {SectionID} -> Topics -> {TopicID} -> Exercises -> {ExerciseID}

Documents wrapped in curly braces being wildcards for documents.

Each Course Document has three "counters":

- numberOfSections
- numberOfTopics
- numberOfExercises

The counters are updated by three different cloud functions (`sectionWriteListener`, `topicWriteListener` and `exerciseWriteListener`), which are all structured similarly:

```
exports.sectionWriteListener =
    functions.region('europe-west1').firestore.document('courses/{courseID}/sections/{sectionID}')
        .onWrite((change, context) => {

            const courseID = context.params.courseID;

            if (!change.before.exists) {
                // New doc, increment count

                return db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).update({ numberOfSections: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) });

            } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
                // Just updating

            } else if (!change.after.exists) {
                // Deleting Doc, decrement count

                return db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).update({ numberOfSections: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) });

            }
        });
```

`onWrite` automatically triggers once a collection or its child documents are modified, but as far as I know does not trigger when its child documents subcollection is.

This leads to following problem:
When a Topic is deleted, `numberOfTopics` in the `CourseID` Document does get decremented by one, however `numberOfExercises` is not decremented, although the Exercises in the Topic have been deleted as well.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this one.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the Cloud Function for adding/deleting exercises (not triggered when deleting parent topic):

```
exports.exerciseWriteListener =
    functions.region('europe-west1').firestore.document('courses/{courseID}/sections/{sectionID}/topics/{topicID}/exercises/{exerciseID}')
        .onWrite((change, context) => {

            const courseID = context.params.courseID;

            if (!change.before.exists) {
                // New document Created : add one to count
                let ref = db.collection('courses').doc(courseID);
                let action = { numberOfExercises: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) };

                // Add one to Count in Course
                return ref.update(action);

            } else if (change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
                // Updating existing document : Do nothing

            } else if (!change.after.exists) {

                return db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).update({ numberOfExercises: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) });

            }
        });
```

Comment: The common way to accomplish this would be to add a Cloud Function that is triggered on an exercise being added or deleted. Is there any specific reason why you're not doing/can't do that?

Comment: I have a cloud function structured the same way as the one in the example `exports.exerciseWriteListener`. However, it does not get triggered when I delete a Topic (or a section, for that matter). I've added my `exerciseWriteListener` Cloud Function to the question.